# Why does my SQL database not work in Android?

Tags: java, android, sql, error-handling

In my app, a click on an image button brings you to the gallery. After clicking on an image I want to call `onActivityResult` to store the image path, but it does not work. In my `LogCat` it always tells me that it crashes when it tries to save the image path.

My `onActivityResult` method:

```
mImageRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(ImageAdapter.KEY_ROWID) : null;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
    Uri uri = data.getData();

    if(uri != null) {
      Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA
      }, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      String image = cursor.getString(0);
      cursor.close();

      if(image != null) {
      // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO SAVE THE IMAGE. HERE MUST BE THE ERROR!
        if (mImageRowId == null) {
          long id = mImageHelper.createImage(image);

          if (id > 0) {
            mImageRowId = id;
          }
        }

        // Set the image and display it in the edit activity
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image);
        mImageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my `onSaveInstanceState` method:

```
private static final Long DEF_ROW_ID = 0L;
  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putLong(ImageAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mImageRowId != null ? mImageRowId : DEF_ROW_ID);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

This is a part from my `DbAdapter`:

```
public long createImage(String image) {
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
  return mImageDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

Can you find the problem?

Comment: Please redo your code indentation and clearly state what you have tried and the exact error you are getting in LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

What's your mImageHelper ?

Otherwise, you're trying to create a bitmap using the variable image containing android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA. But this column is not the file path :)

make a query on your data object received in onActivityresult (data.getData) to retrieve  column MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA.

You should create your image from the path.

Good luck.